# My program isn't sorting properly

Tags: python-3.x

Im making a histogram from a file and I got it working however its not sorting them correctly. Meaning 100 90 50 etc.

Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
data=[]
with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    data.append(str(line))

counts = Counter(data)

for key, size in sorted(counts.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, int(size) * '*'))
```

This is the output:

```
100: ******
25: **
50: ***
60: *
65: *
70: **
75: *
80: ****
85: ****
90: ***
```

Any suggestions??

EDIT:

What I mean is that they go numerically in order. So insted of 100, 25, 50, .... I want it 100, 90, 85,.....

Comment: that looks sorted to me

Comment: what I mean is that the go numerically in order. So insted of 100, 25, 50, .... I want it 100, 90, 85,.....

Comment: you sort on the tuple, the first item of the tuple is the "key", the key is a string, that's an alphabetical order. You need to parse the string as a number if you want to have a numerical order.

Comment: How would that look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

njzk2 is absolutely right, thanks!
One way you can do it is like this :

```
...
line = line.strip()
# casting to 'int' type just before populating in data table..
data.append(int(line)) 
...
```

then, you can

```
...
# applying reversed to reorder from ascending order to descending order.
for key, size in sorted(counts.items(), reverse=True):
...
```